# client server ios app using AFNetwork and JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, server, client, afnetworking

I have iPhone application (written in Objective-C), which connects to a remote database stored on a server - the problem is that I didn't program the app, another developer did.

I know that they wrote the remote database using the *Clojure* language, then stored it on a server and protected it by ssh authentication using private and public keys.

After that they got the data from the remote database using the `AFNetworking` library and parsed the data using JSON.

When running the app connects with the server and fetches the data via JSON and stores it in a local SQLite database.

I don't know how I do that, and would like to learn how. Any advice regarding where can I learn more about this, any decent resources?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link

https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

With this link, You should get basic idea how afnetworking can be used to establish client server app in IOS